# Using Directives with Leaflet markers

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I'm playing some experiments using AngularJS and Leaftlet (I'm new at both of them). I see I can specify some `HTML` as `markers.bindPopup(...);` parameter. Does anyone tryied to show an AngularJS directive as parameter? I tryed this way whit no success (no surprise) `bindPopup(<myDummyDirective></myDummyDirective>)`. I want to show my directive as marker's popup, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$compile`:

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

```
$compile('<myDummyDirective></myDummyDirective>')(scope);
```

See the reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Hello! Finally I put my hands on that again. I tried what you suggest without success `... .bindPopup($compile('<pgform></pgform>')($scope));`. Maybe because `<myDummyDirective>` is not the directive in which i want to open the marker's popup?

Comment: Ok, I managed to run my custom directive into marker's popup. As iH8 suggests I used `$compile`, here is the way I do that:
`var lf = $compile(angular.element('<div><pgform></pgform></div>'))($scope.$new());`
`marker.bindPopup(lf[0]);`